# Python (Pygame) spawning in time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a game in Pygame(I´m still new to python and Pygame I know the basics but that's pretty much it) but when I try to spawn to the enemies they appear at different times (they are supposed to appear in a line and go down at the same time)

This is the part that gives me trouble:

```
blocks_list = [enemy_pos]
block_speed = 10
gameover = False

def dropper(blocks_list):
    if len(blocks_list) <= random.randint(5,10):
        dropper.x_pos = (random.randint(1,13) * p_size) + 10
        dropper.y_pos = 0
        blocks_list.append([dropper.x_pos,dropper.y_pos])

def move_blocks():
    for enemy_pos in blocks_list:
        enemy_pos[1] = enemy_pos[1] + block_speed

def draw_blocks(blocks_list):
    long = len(blocks_list)
    print(long)
    
    for enemy_pos in blocks_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,(enemy_pos[0],enemy_pos[1],p_size,p_size))


def drawing(blocks_list):
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    draw_blocks(blocks_list)

    move_blocks()

While not gameover:
    drawing(blocks_list)
```

[THIS are photos of what is happenning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rID4K.png)

[como see deberia de ver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bp1P.png)

I've tried putting it in a while loop to see if it appears all at once.

Full code:

```
#IMPORT THE IMPORTANT
import pygame
import sys
import random

pygame.init()



#screen size
SW = 320
SH = 600

#colors
RED = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)

#Barier vars
barrier1x = SH/20
barrier1y = SH
barrier2x = SW
barrier2y = SH/20

#player vars
p_size = 20
p_x = (SW/2)-(p_size/2)
p_y = (SH/20 * 17)
p_speed = 20
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SW,SH))

#falling? blocks vars
enemy_pos = [-30,0]
blocks_list = [enemy_pos]
block_speed = 10

gameover = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()



#functions  
def draw_player():
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GREEN,(p_x,p_y,p_size,p_size))

def dropper(blocks_list):
    if len(blocks_list) <= random.randint(5,10):
        dropper.x_pos = (random.randint(1,13) * p_size) + 10
        dropper.y_pos = 0
        blocks_list.append([dropper.x_pos,dropper.y_pos])

def move_blocks():
    for enemy_pos in blocks_list:
        enemy_pos[1] = enemy_pos[1] + block_speed

def draw_blocks(blocks_list):
    long = len(blocks_list)
    a=1
    print(long)
    
    for enemy_pos in blocks_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,(enemy_pos[0],enemy_pos[1],p_size,p_size))
    
def barrier():
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE,(0,0,barrier1x,barrier1y))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE,(0,0,barrier2x,barrier2y))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE,(SW-barrier1x,0,barrier1x,barrier1y))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,(0,SH-barrier2y,barrier2x,barrier2y))

def collision_always():
    global p_x
    global p_y
    global gameover
    if p_x <= SW/20:
        p_x = p_x + p_speed
    if p_x >= SW-barrier1x:
        p_x = p_x - p_speed
    if p_y <= SW/20:
        p_y = p_y + p_speed
    if p_y >= SH - (SH/20):
        gameover = True;
        print("u ded");

def drawing(blocks_list):
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    barrier()
    
    draw_player()
    
    draw_blocks(blocks_list)

    move_blocks()

    pygame.display.update()

def controls():
    global p_y
    global p_x
    global p_speed
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                p_x = p_x - p_speed
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                p_x = p_x + p_speed
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                p_y = p_y - p_speed
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                p_y = p_y + p_speed



#main loop
while not gameover:

    dropper(blocks_list)

    controls()

    collision_always()

    drawing(blocks_list)
    
    clock.tick(30)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you call `dropper(blocks_list)` every loop iteration, it's continuously adding enemies to the screen. If you add some in one iteration, then they drop a little bit, and then you add more enemies the next loop iteration, they'll be higher up than the ones created in the previous iteration. `if len(blocks_list) <= random.randint(5,10)` means that all the enemies won't necessarily get added in the first iteration; a random amount gets added per iteration.

So, in order to have all the enemies drop at the same time, one option is to add them all at once before you start your loop. e.g. move `dropper(blocks_list)` to above `while not gameover:`.

Comment: i´ll try that brb

Comment: okey i just realized my mistake was that i had a if instead of a while thank you  very much Random Davis